# Gigya Share bar Customization - buttonWithCountTemplate

Tags: facebook, google-plus-one, gigya

I have asked a question regarding customizing the share bar especially providers facebook-like and google-plusone (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18330929/gigya-sharebar-unable-to-change-icon-for-facebook-like-and-google-plusone). But no answers so far. I was wondering if it can be done using buttonWithCountTemplate. I want to set the icons for facebook-like and google-plusone in sharebar using buttonWithCountTemplate. But there seems to be no example code that shows buttonWithCountTemplate usage. Can anyone provide the example usage of buttonWithCountTemplate in Gigya Share Bar Customization.

Comment: I have tried buttonWithCountTemplate but it still doesnt change facebook-like.... Anyone knows a way to change the icon for facebook-like and google-plusone providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is a string value which you can use the following placeholders in: $iconImg, $text, $onClick, $count.

You would add the parameter like so:

```
buttonWithCountTemplate: '<div class="sBtnWrap"><a href="#" onclick="$onClick"><div class="sBtn">$text<img src="$iconImg" /></div><div class="sCountBox">$count</div></a></div>'
```

Unfortunately it seems you can not control the styling of all the providers like facebook like or any of the goole providers. If you change facebook-like to just facebook as the provider it will be styleable.

Comment: Could you explain what each of the placeholders are?  I believe that `$iconImg` is the icon that you send in iconImgUp, `$onClick` is the function that gigya fires off on click, `$count` is the number of likes/shares/tweets/etc, but what is `$text`?

Comment: @allicarn `$text` actually outputs the providers name, so in a template if the provider is Facebook `$text` will output "Facebook". Thats what I found in usage, Gigya's documentation doesn't appear to explain these.